# Image covers sticky block when I use transform

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use `img:hover  {transform: scale(1.1)}` and the image covers my sticky `nav` block:
[when my cursor is on the first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QYTf.jpg)

I'd prefer if the image will behind the sticky block. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by either changing the z-index of the sticky block or the image. Try doing `z-index: 1;` on the sticky block.